# Connecting to MySQL database through Node after MySQLDUMP

Tags: mysql, node.js

i've imported a mysql database from old to new machine using mysqldump. on the new machine, i can read the local database and print the database contents to the console, meaning the import worked.

To connect to this database, i'm using Node (eg `node myServerFile.js`) but it's not connecting to this database on the new machine. my react/node files are exactly the same on both machines, the difference is a new machine with a freshly installed react/node/mysql environment.

i can't get past the 'Error connecting to database' message

myServerFile.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'xxxx',
  password: 'xxxx',
  database: 'xxxx'
});

var router = express();

connection.connect(function(err){
  if(!err) {
    console.log('Database is connected');    
  } 
  else {
    console.log('Error connecting to database');    
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "not connecting"? Do you get errors? If so, please include the *exact* error text.

Comment: did you recreate the users that you where using for the connection in the new server?

Comment: users recreated - yes

Comment: check privileges, especially host from where user can connect to database

Comment: grant all privileges on database to specified user - yes

Comment: It could be the port.. or the new machine can't connect through `localhost` etc. I'm guessing the old machine is something like Windows 7 and the new machine is Windows 10.

Comment: on both machines, confirmed mysql default port @3306 and even explicitly specified this port number under 'var connection' but no change; both machines run win10

Comment: A few other factors like windows firewall blocking the port or blocking the mysql entirely could cause it. Or node js being blocked. It's strange since you said both run windows 10, both using same port, all privileges has been granted but still can't connect to database.

Comment: Can you connect to the database if using tool like mysql workbench?

Comment: turned off firewall and virus scan; connected via workbench - works; i've reinstalled older versions of mysql server and node but no change